# How to get key for Google Maps for releasing version?

Tags: java, android

I have to create application with Google Maps. I have generated MD5 code and got key; it works good for testing. But If I export project into final .apk than it won't work. I undestand that releasing version is cause of it. How can I got key for final version of application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to run

`keytool -list -alias <YOUR_RELEASE_ALIAS> -keystore <YOUR_KEYSTORE_FILE>`

that will give you the MD5 Certificate fingerprint, which you have to copy and paste here:

http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

That will give you the release API key which you must use in your `MapView`